# How to display an image on a MKOverlayView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, mapkit

**UPDATE:**

Images who are projected on the MKMapView using a MKOverlayView use the [Mercator projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection), while the image that I use as input data uses a WGS84 projection. Is there a way to convert the input image, to the right projection WGS84 -> Mercator, without tiling the image up and can it done on the fly?

Normally you could convert a image to right projection using the program [gdal2tiles](http://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html).
The input data however changes every fifteen minutes, so the image has to be converted every fifteen minutes. So the conversion has to be done on the fly. I also want the tiling to be done by Mapkit and not by myself using gdal2tiles or the GDAL framework.

**UPDATE END**

I'm currently working on a project which displays a rainfall radar over some part of the world. The radar image is provided by EUMETSAT, they offer a KML file which can be loaded into Google Earth or Google Maps. If I load the KML file in Google Maps it displays perfectly, but if I draw the image using a MKOverlayView on a MKMapView, the image is slightly of.

For example, on the left side, Google Maps and on the right side the same image is displayed at a MKMapView.

[image]

[image]

The surface that the image covers can be viewed on [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=nl&geocode=&q=http:%2F%2Foiswww.eumetsat.org%2FIPPS%2Fhtml%2FGE%2FEUM.kml&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=48.287373,114.169922&ie=UTF8&ll=32.842674,7.734375&spn=150.886926,96.679687&z=2), the satellite that is used for the image is the "Meteosat 0 Degree" satellite.

The surface that both images cover is of the same size, this is the LatLonBox from the KML file, it specifies where the top, bottom, right, and left sides of a bounding box for the ground overlay are aligned.

```
  <LatLonBox id="GE_MET0D_VP-MPE-latlonbox">
        <north>57.4922</north>
        <south>-57.4922</south>
        <east>57.4922</east>
        <west>-57.4922</west>
        <rotation>0</rotation>
  </LatLonBox>
```

I create a new custom MKOverlay object called RadarOverlay with these parameters,

```
[[RadarOverlay alloc] initWithImageData:[[self.currentRadarData objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Image"] withLowerLeftCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-57.4922, -57.4922) withUpperRightCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(57.4922, 57.4922)];
```

The implementation of the custom MKOverlay object; RadarOverlay

```
- (id) initWithImageData:(NSData*) imageData withLowerLeftCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)lowerLeftCoordinate withUpperRightCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)upperRightCoordinate
{
     self.radarData = imageData;

     MKMapPoint lowerLeft = MKMapPointForCoordinate(lowerLeftCoordinate);
     MKMapPoint upperRight = MKMapPointForCoordinate(upperRightCoordinate);

     mapRect = MKMapRectMake(lowerLeft.x, upperRight.y, upperRight.x - lowerLeft.x, lowerLeft.y - upperRight.y);

     return self;
}

- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
     return MKCoordinateForMapPoint(MKMapPointMake(MKMapRectGetMidX(mapRect), MKMapRectGetMidY(mapRect)));
}

- (MKMapRect)boundingMapRect
{
     return mapRect;
}
```

The implementation of the custom MKOverlayView, RadarOverlayView

```
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    RadarOverlay* radarOverlay = (RadarOverlay*) self.overlay;

    UIImage *image          = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:radarOverlay.radarData];

    CGImageRef imageReference = image.CGImage;

    MKMapRect theMapRect    = [self.overlay boundingMapRect];
   CGRect theRect           = [self rectForMapRect:theMapRect];
    CGRect clipRect     = [self rectForMapRect:mapRect];

    NSUserDefaults *preferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    CGContextSetAlpha(context, [preferences floatForKey:@"RadarTransparency"]);

    CGContextAddRect(context, clipRect);
    CGContextClip(context);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, theRect, imageReference);

    [image release]; 
}
```

When I download the image, I flip the image so it can be easily drawn in the MKOverlayView

```
size_t width    = (CGImageGetWidth(imageReference) / self.scaleFactor);
size_t height   = (CGImageGetHeight(imageReference) / self.scaleFactor);

// Calculate colorspace for the specified image
CGColorSpaceRef imageColorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(imageReference);

// Allocate and clear memory for the data of the image
unsigned char *imageData = (unsigned char*) malloc(height * width * 4);
memset(imageData, 0, height * width * 4);

// Define the rect for the image
CGRect imageRect;
if(image.imageOrientation==UIImageOrientationUp || image.imageOrientation==UIImageOrientationDown) 
    imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height); 
else 
    imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, height, width); 

// Create the imagecontext by defining the colorspace and the address of the location to store the data
CGContextRef imageContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(imageData, width, height, 8, width * 4, imageColorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

CGContextSaveGState(imageContext);

// Scale the image to the opposite orientation so it can be easylier drawn with CGContectDrawImage
CGContextTranslateCTM(imageContext, 0, height);
CGContextScaleCTM(imageContext, 1.0, -1.0);

if(image.imageOrientation==UIImageOrientationLeft) 
{
    CGContextRotateCTM(imageContext, M_PI / 2);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(imageContext, 0, -width);
}
else if(image.imageOrientation==UIImageOrientationRight) 
{
    CGContextRotateCTM(imageContext, - M_PI / 2);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(imageContext, -height, 0);
} 
else if(image.imageOrientation==UIImageOrientationDown) 
{
    CGContextTranslateCTM(imageContext, width, height);
    CGContextRotateCTM(imageContext, M_PI);
}

// Draw the image in the context
CGContextDrawImage(imageContext, imageRect, imageReference);
CGContextRestoreGState(imageContext);
```

After I flipped the image, I manipulate it and then store it in memory as a NSData object.

It looks like the image got stretched, but it looks allright at the center of the image, which is at the equator.

Comment: I'm completely out of my depth here, but might this problem have something to do with the fact that while latitudinal distance is constant (~111km/degree) everywhere, longitudinal distance varies as cos(phi)*R_e?

Comment: This would be the case if you draw the image on a spherical object, but according to the documentation; http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html everything should be drawn correctly because it is a flat surface

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue, just with different radar data. Google Maps is drawing the KML perfectly but when I draw it with an MKOverlayRenderer it's off a bit, both lat and long.

Answer (score 5):

Have you already seen "Session 127 - Customizing Maps with Overlays" from the WWDC 2010 videos? One of the examples takes earthquake data, which gives the earthquake risk for 0.5 by 0.5 degree areas and maps them. Your radar data looks similar, based on squares. The sample code has a full application called HazardMaps, which takes this data and creates an overlay using MKMapPoints. If you haven't already seen this video, I think it will give you plenty of useful information. He also talks about converting to the Mercator projection.

Another thing to check is what coordinate system (datum) the data from EUMETSAT is in. Google Maps uses a system called [WGS-84](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System), which is a general standard. But there are many other standards which can give more accurate positions in different parts of the world. If you use the latitude and longitude from a different standard in Google Maps, all your points will be off by a certain amount. The offset is not consistent, it changes as you move around the map. It's possible that Google Maps is being smart about the data and converting to WGS-84 on the fly.

You might find out more details by looking at the KML. I looked but couldn't find the final KML, with the rectangles. Perhaps it gives information about what coordinate system it's using in the metadata.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've already watched that video, the difference between this project and the HazardMap project is that the Hazardmap project downloads a file containing data for each of the specific rectangles, while in my project I download one PNG file containing the data for all. The kml file that I use can be found here, http://oiswww.eumetsat.int/IPPS/html/GE/MET0D_VP-MPE.kml, maybe you can take a look at it? I think Google Maps converts the image on the fly, the only question is, how would this be done on the iPhone?

Comment: In that video he mentions also a project called TileMap, in that project the image is displayed correctly on the map, the only thing is that the image is tiled up beforehand. When I draw an image in an overlay on the map it is automatically tiled by the iOS system. I think, when they tile up the image in the TileMap project, it is converted to use the Mercator projection. They tile it up using the following program, http://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html

Comment: Maybe this link can also be of use, http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Tile_Map_Service_Specification

Comment: OK, I see now that it's using a png instead of data. About the TileMap, it is created beforehand using gdal, so you can't use that approach. Here's a couple more suggestions: Try creating your own png, a black square 2048x2048. This is the same size as their image. Put it in your app and check where the corners touch. Are they far from the 57.4922 latitude and longitude points? The "57.4922, 57.4922" http://goo.gl/maps/ohXR point is over land, so it should be easiest. Second, are you only converting the center coordinate? Try converting all corner coordinates and squeezing the image into that.

Comment: Well the corners touch each other, http://dev.jeroendeleeuw.nl/upperrightlocation.png, this is the coordinate "57.4922, 57.4922". The placement of the image on the map seems correct, it covers the right surface, the problem, I think is, how it is converted. What do you mean exactly by converting the center coordinate and the corners coordinates. Thanks for looking into it and for your help.

Comment: I thought you only used `MKCoordinateForMapPoint` for the center coordinate. I hadn't noticed the code above that where you convert the lower left and upper right, so I thought you were only converting the center point. My mistake. If your image is setting its corners at the correct positions, then the problem might be the coordinate system. Find out the coordinate system that they are using. The link you gave mentions "Spatial Referencing Systems". Try to find out if it's WGS-84/Mercator. Sorry I can't help more, I'm not an expert on this, but I've been through the same kind of problem.

Comment: You were correct, the problem is, the image has a WGS84 projection, while Mapkit expects a Mercator projection. My final question is, is there a way to convert the image, without tiling it up, to the mercator projection, on the fly? Can you help with that?

Comment: It seems strange that the maps on the iPhone would be using something different than on the web. I'm not an expert, but I thought that Mercator and WGS-84 were fundamentally different things. Mercator is a way of showing a sphere on a flat surface, while WGS-84 is a standard for positioning on a map. Mercator is from the 1500s, WGS-84 is from the 80s. When I've converted on iPhone, I've always converted to WGS-84. I think that trying to stretch the image is the wrong approach. Is there not a set of parameters you can use when requesting the image, with the projection? Perhaps one is WGS-84.

Comment: You are right, WGS84 is a coordinate system, what I mean is this, "Simple cylindrical projection (or Plate Carrée) is a simple map projection where the meridians and parallels are equidistant, straight parallel lines, with the two sets crossing at right angles. (This format is also known as Lat/Lon WGS84 projection.)" from http://earth.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=22373&topic=22376&answer=148098. This projection is used to create Google Maps/Earth overlays. It is converted to a mercator projection on the fly.

Comment: Thus the image is created with a "Plate Carree" projection while the MKMapView expects a mercator projection. To answer your question on why the maps use the mercator projection, http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/maps/thread?tid=075eb10962e00cc5&hl=en

Comment: OK, that explains it. They are giving you WGS-84, but the projection is different. If you were using points instead of a flat image, it would be easy to convert. With an image you would have to use some sort of complicated transform to convert it. Like I said before, you should find out if there are other versions of the image available (possibly requesting the image using some extra parameters) before you try to do image transforms.

Comment: If you do decide to try transforming the image, PROJ.4 might help you (http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/).

Comment: The bounty for this question is ending in two hours and I'm awarding it to you for all of your help. Thank you for that. The question isn't yet solved but I came a long way in the last couple of days, I also posted a new question on the Apple forums, in the hope that they will help me further with it. If there are any more update, I will let you know.

Comment: Glad to help, and I learned some stuff as well. You could also try calling or emailing the eumetsat people, I'd say they could give you a quick answer. Post the answer when you find out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would affect the scaling issue, but in your OverlayView code, your drawing the entire image for every maptile.

Have you tried only drawing the portion of the image that is visible in mapRect?

When I've had problems with MKOverlayViews, its been helpful for me to draw the rect of the overlay (self.overlay.boundingRect) and the mapRect (passed into drawMapRect).  Although, I'm not sure if drawing the mapRect would be helpful in your situation.

At any rate, heres the function I use to draw the rect in case you want to try it out

```
-(void)drawRect:(MKMapRect)rect inContext:(CGContextRef)context withLineWidth:(float)lineWidth andColor:(CGColorRef)color
{

    double maxx = MKMapRectGetMaxX(rect);
    double minx = MKMapRectGetMinX(rect);
    double maxy = MKMapRectGetMaxY(rect);
    double miny = MKMapRectGetMinY(rect);

    CGPoint tr = [self pointForMapPoint:(MKMapPoint) {maxx, maxy}];
    CGPoint br = [self pointForMapPoint:(MKMapPoint) {maxx, miny}];
    CGPoint bl = [self pointForMapPoint:(MKMapPoint) {minx, miny}];
    CGPoint tl = [self pointForMapPoint:(MKMapPoint) {minx, maxy}];

    CGMutablePathRef cgPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(cgPath, NULL, tr.x, tr.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(cgPath, NULL, br.x, br.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(cgPath, NULL, bl.x, bl.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(cgPath, NULL, tl.x, tl.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(cgPath, NULL, tr.x, tr.y); 

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextAddPath(context, cgPath);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);
    CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGPathRelease(cgPath);  
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Comment: I have already implemented that in my code, it clips the visible rect so only that portion of the overlay is been drawn. I will update it in my source code. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that Google Maps is stretching the image non-linearly to compensate for the map projection and that your code/Apple's code isn't.

One possible solution would be to subdivide the overlay image into smaller rectangles and call MKMapPointForCoordinate() separately for each rectangle. Then the data will be much closer to being correct.

Answer (score 1):

WGS-84 data is using UTM projection, MKMapView is using mercator. You are using different methods to map a 3D object to a 2D surface, hence it is not giving the same results.

You'll need to go down in GDAL and move the incomming image to a different projection. Let me know if you figured it out, because it ain't an easy

Answer (score 0):

Your image/overlay is most likely no longer proportional (i.e. it's been stretched).  I've seen this kind of thing in my own app where the center of the view is correct, but as you go away from the equator toward either pole (top and bottom of screen) the map/overlay becomes increasingly distorted.

You are obviously scaling your image by scaleFactor.  I'd take a look at that for starters.

```
size_t width    = (CGImageGetWidth(imageReference) / self.scaleFactor);
size_t height   = (CGImageGetHeight(imageReference) / self.scaleFactor);
```

Another good way to test your code to see if scaling is the culprit, is to scale your MKMapView down to the size of the overlay image.  Leave the overlay image alone, and if it is no longer distorted then you know that is the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the scale factor that I use for testing is always 1, so it won't be scaled by me, in this case I will comment out all the scaling code. I don't exactly understand what you mean by "is to scale your MKMapView down to the size of the overlay image", the overlay image itself is 2048x2048 pixels, but it needs to get stretched, see the Google Maps link for that. It only gets stretched in the wrong way. How did you solve it? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Either make the mkmapview 2048x2048. Or scale the image Down to say 320x320. Then make your mkmapview 320x320. I'm not sure why the image has to be stretched (I'm typing this on an iPod so I can't really follow that link right now).

Comment: Changing the size of the MKMapView has no effect, the MKMapView is just a rectangle layed out over the world map which gets clipped. Changing the size will only change the rectangle, but is has no effect on the world map itself or on any annotations or overlays displayed on the world map. The surface of the MKOverlayView seems correct and it seems to correspond with the surface of the overlay on Google Maps, the only difference is the way it gets stretched.

Comment: Yes, but the MKRegion may cause it be stretched.  Your latitude span, longitude span should match up with the width/height ratio of the MKMapView.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it didn't work. http://dev.jeroendeleeuw.nl/image.png Do you have another solution, how did you solve it in your own project?

Comment: Jeroen, Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, not yet, I started a bounty for this question, hopefully somebody will have a solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a sample app from WWDC that parses KML and displays it on a map.  If you are a paid developer you can access it from the [WWDC videos page in iTunes](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/).  I recommend using their parser.

Comment: The parsing is not the problem, the problem is how you implement the parsed data on a MKOverlayView

Comment: And Apple's parser takes care of that.

Comment: It does not, not in the sample application "KMLViewer" as you suggested, but you put me in the right direction. The MKMapView uses Mercator projection, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection, that's why the image is stretched that way. So the image has to be converted to use that projection, I think? Do you know how to do that?