# what is the relation of MKMaprect and CGRect

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

I am drawing an image as overlay for MKMapview, for this I need to know relation between MKMapRect and CGRect to draw image in a rect for visible maprect,.

I didnt find any solution.., please suggest me if any one knows,

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some thing which will solve you problem in drawing an image as overlay for MKMapview please have a look on already asked **[How to display an image on a MKOverlayView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891850/how-to-display-an-image-on-a-mkoverlayview)** try to draw the rectangle around it through this method

`-(void)drawRect:(MKMapRect)rect inContext:(CGContextRef)context withLineWidth:(float)lineWidth andColor:(CGColorRef)color`

Good Luck