# How to save image on Google map in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, camera, mapkit

I have map application in which I have a button. On clicking that button the user can capture image through iPhone and the image that is captured by the user should be save on the map at the particular location where he has captured the image.

Comment: while clickin on the camera button it tells to capture image.But i dont know how to save this image to my location on map

Comment: is map Currently running ? i.e. how do you recognize you need to store at this location ? center of the map ? or based on GPS or something else ?

Comment: This question can be closed as Too Broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know where you want to display image on map then you have two ways to display particular image on map.
1. You can add image as a overlay on map.
Below link contains code in question: [code link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891850/how-to-display-an-image-on-a-mkoverlayview)
2. Add image as a annoation. (http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use core location to get the user current location, so that you can get his location where he is capturing image and then show that location on map.

Answer (score 0):

By "save on the map" I'm assuming you want to show a dropped pin on the spot where the photo was taken- to do this, you'll need to:

1. Get the user's current location with [CLLocationManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) and [CLLocationManagerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/CLLocationManagerDelegate).
2. Use [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) to let the user take the photo.
3. Use [MKAnnotation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [MKPinAnnotationView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPinAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to drop a pin where the user's location is. You can even insert the picture in the annotation view's callout.

A bit of Googling will net you tutorials using these classes. [This one](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2009/04/02/iphone-sdk-30-playing-with-map-kit/) looks decent.