# How to get effect like HazardMap on dropped annotations in mapView iPhone?

Tags: iphone, annotations, heatmap

I want to Make heat map (HazardMap) based on annotations dropped to the mapView. If i have more annotation than the location should be red. How to do This. Please anyone help me? [like This Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891850/how-to-display-an-image-on-a-mkoverlayview)